# Compare two blender files

Tags: workflow

I'm manipulating .bvh files from CMU and need a way to quantify the difference in movement from one blender file to another. The rig, mesh, and position of the actor is held constant while the movement of the actor in place is manipulated (e.g.higher knee elevation when marching in place).

Is there a script or a program out there that would give me the difference in the movement between the two blender files?